# Getting data from get request?

Tags: ajax, node.js

I'm sending an ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url:"/game/set",
   data: JSON.stringify({colour: col, size: size}),
   success: function(){console.log("SUCCESS.")},
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

I can receive the request on the server just fine, but I can't figure out how to pull the data from it before responding. He is how I'm handling it.

```
var jsonString = '';
req.setEncoding('utf8');

req.on('data', function (data) {
   jsonString += data;
});

req.on('end', function () {

   reqData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
   respond(200, JSON.stringify(reqData));

});
```

but I seem to get this error when trying to parse.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: Can you add `console.log(jsonString)` before `reqData = JSON.parse(jsonString);` and show the output

Comment: Try changing the method from GET to POST so it'll send a body with your data in the request. You don't need to stringify, just pass the object the way it is.

Comment: You can't send data in a get request.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send data in a `GET` request. Try `POST` instead.